# New column from slices of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with time series data with pandas and my data frame looks a little bit like this

```
           Date         Layer
0    2000-01-01       0.408640
1    2000-01-02       0.842065
2    2000-01-03       1.271810
3    2000-01-04       1.699399
4    2000-01-05       2.128098
        ...            ...
7300 2019-12-27     149.323520
7301 2019-12-28     149.744012
7302 2019-12-29     150.155702
7303 2019-12-30     150.562771
7304 2019-12-31     151.003031
```

I need to make a column for each year, like this:

```
        2000        2001      2002
0     0.408640   0.415863   0.425689
1     0.852653   0.826542   0.863524   
        ...        ...         ...
364  156.235978 158.564578 152.135689
365  156.685421 158.924556 152.528978
```

Is there a way I can manage to do that? The resulting data can be in a new data frame

Answer (score 2):

The approach for this will be to create separate year and day of year columns, and then create a pivot table:

```
#Convert Date column to pandas datetime if you haven't already:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#Create year column
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
#Create day of year column
df['DayOfYear'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofyear
#create pivot table in new dataframe
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'DayOfYear', columns = 'Year', values = 'Layer')
```

This won't look exactly like your desired output because the index will be numbered 1-365 (and have a name) rather than 0-364. If you want it to match exactly, you can add:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```